# How do I use the Accurev Command Line Interface to Add and Retrieve Attachments

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

I am currently building a new web application to interact with the **Accurev Command Line Interface** to

1. create new issues inside the web application and upload to Accurev.
2. query current Accurev issues and display the results in the application.

What I need is some way to add attachment functionality:

1. Download and retrieve the attachments attached to an Accurev issue.
2. Upload and add new attachments to a new or existing Accurev issue using the comman line interface.

Has anyone ever done anything like this? The **Accurev Command Line Interface** documentation does not have any references to downloading or uploading attachments in it.

Comment: Try asking on the AccuRev forum, as well: http://www.accurev.com/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php/category/2/General_Discussion

Comment: See technote 217 from the forum.

Comment: FAQ 217: How can I retrieve an AccuWork issue attachment from the cli.